Openweathermap > json / fetch / property is not always available resulting in undefined
I'm trying to get this to work:
(removed app id)
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=39.561937&lon=2.936562&appid=XXX&units=metric&lang=de')
        .then(data => data.json())

     .then(data => {
    const description1 = data.weather[0].description;
    const temperature = data.main.temp;
    const feels = data.main.feels_like;
    const wind1 = data.wind.speed;
    const rain = data.rain['1h'] || '0';

    const weatherIcon = document.querySelector('.icon img'); 
    const iconURL = `https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;
    weatherIcon.setAttribute('src', iconURL);

    // Update the weather values on your web page
    document.querySelector('#description1').innerText = description1;
    document.querySelector('#temperature').innerText = (Math.round(temperature));
    document.querySelector('#feels').innerText = (Math.round(feels));
    document.querySelector('#wind1').innerText = (Math.round(wind1 *3.6));
    document.querySelector('#rain').innerText = rain;


  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

The const "rain" > data.rain['1h'] is not always available, if it's available the code above works, but if it's not available it results in: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1h')"
I tried to fix it with " || '0'; but that doesn't seem to work...
Basically if there is no rain, it should show 0.
Thank you for your help!

Use the symbol "?" to prevent such errors:
 const rain = data?.rain?.['1h'] || '0';


Wow you rock! That's awesome! It works like a charm! Can you shortly explain why that worked? Does the ? mean it checks for a return value and if not > shows 0?

"?." checks the value for undefined, and if the value does not exist, then undefined is returned instead of an error

Ok great, so what about the '1h' variable.... there is no ? there, is that alright?
